# Javascript Image Gallery with Array

Tags: javascript, html, image-gallery

I'm trying to modify html img source with anchors that trigger javascript on click, but it's not working. Here's my code:

HTML

```
<body>
<img src='./images/img1.png' id='gallery'>
<a href="#" id="back">Back</a> - <a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
</body>
```

JS

```
var image = new Array(3)
image[1]="./images/img1.png"
image[2]="./images/img2.png"
image[3]="./images/img3.png"
var num = 1;

document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', function(galleryNext){
num=num+1
if (num==4)
{num=1}
document.getElementById('gallery').src=image[num];
});

document.getElementById('back').addEventListener('click', function(galleryPrevious){
num=num-1
if (num==0)
{num=3}
document.getElementById('gallery').src=image[num];
});
```

Comment: Its working fine... http://jsfiddle.net/BEDwY/2/

Answer (score 0):

well, put the js code inside a function and call it on the `onload` event of body

Comment: Could we have an example please.